# Can I have one public tag within my private repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a private repository, but I would like to make one of my tags publicly available. Is it possible?

Comment: Why?  If the repository is private, the commit that the tag points to is meaningless.  What's the use case or problem you're trying to solve with a public tag and a private repository?

Comment: I have a project within a repository and I want a tag to be available for download for one person, but she can't see the hole project, because there's another client. Isn't it possible?

Comment: While I never tried it, a quick google search turned up [Keeping parts of your codebase private on Github](https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/).  Might want to check that out.

Comment: I could work with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Post it as answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a possible solution may be to use separate remotes and keep your public/private sections in different branches.  I know Stackoverflow frowns upon link-only solutions, but I'd hate to repeat and/or copy/paste the details so here's the link:

[Keeping Parts of Your Codebase Private on GitHub](https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/)